# Pushed apps into device from google play web browser, install failed. How to find out what apps failed?

Tags: google-play-store, installation, logging

Yesterday I browsed into the play store from my pc, and selected several apps to be installed onto my tablet.

The tablet attempted to install the apps later, but several of them failed. I have cleared the notifications, now I don't remember what apps were not installed.

How can I retrieve this list of failed install attempts? I don't know what apps I tried to install (or I would just re-install them).

Device is a Samsung G-note 2014ed, running on 5.1.1

Comment: Ummmmmmm...... Logcat? I doubt it though, since you rebooted. Try installing them again, and nab a screenshot

Comment: If I knew what apps were in that batch, I would just reinstall them. @DanBrown

Comment: Then You can't AFAIK.

Comment: @DanBrown I was hoping google play would keep a list or log somewhere.

Comment: If you have only never installed them before, you could find them in the all section of my apps

Answer (score -1):

Your android version is lower version or, you must download the apps on your playstore tablet not on browser CMIIW

Comment: Play Store already filters compatible devices when trying to install an app from the web store. Thus, trying to install an app that requires higher Android version is impossible in the first place.